Should coffee machines be placed at the region's boundary?
This is a continuation of Should coffee machines be deconcentrated?
Recall that some region is denoted by convex and compact $E\subset \mathbb R^2$. $N\ge 1$ coffee machines are provided for the people living on $E$, of capacities $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_N>0$. Assume the population of $E$ is uniformly distributed such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n = \ell(E),$$
where $\ell$ is the Lebesgue measure. If locating the machines at $x_1,\ldots, x_N\in E$ with $X:=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$, the transportation cost is given as
$$F(X):=W_2(\mu_X,\ell) \quad\mbox{with}\quad \mu_X:=\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n\delta_{x_n}, \quad\quad  \forall X\in E^N,$$
where $W_2$ denotes the Wasserstein metric of order $2$. As $F:E^N\to\mathbb R_+$ is Lipschitz and $E^N$ is compact, its minimum is attained. Can we find a minimiser $X^*=(x_1^*,\ldots, x_N^*)\in E^N$ belonging to the interior of $E^N$? Namely $x_n^* \notin \partial E$ for all $n=1,\ldots, N$.


By $\ell$, do you actually mean the uniform distribution over $E$?

$\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\newcommand{\p}{\partial}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Without loss of generality (wlog), $\ell$ is the uniform probability distribution over $E$ and hence
$\sum_{i=1}^N\al_i=1$. Here it is assumed that the interior $E^\circ$ of $E$ is nonempty.
Let $\Ga$ be the set of all probability distributions $\ga$ over $E\times E$ such that for some $(x_1,\dots,x_N)\in E^N$ the marginals of $\ga$ are $\sum_{i\in[N]}\al_i\de_{x_i}$ and $\ell$, where
$[N]:=\{1,\dots,N\}$. Informally, $\ga(X\times A)$ is the mass transported from a set $X$ to a set $A$ under the plan $\ga$.
Let $\ga^*\in\Ga$ with marginals $\sum_{i\in[N]}\al_i\de_{x_i^*}$ and $\ell$ be an optimal transportation plan in the sense that
\begin{equation*}
    C(\ga):=\int_E|x-y|^2\,\ga(dx\times dy)\ge C(\ga^*)
\end{equation*}
for all $\ga\in\Ga$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Claim: $x_i^*\in E^\circ$ for all $i\in[N]$.

Proof: Suppose the contrary. Then wlog $x_1^*\in\p E$. So, wlog $x_1^*=(0,0)$ and $(s,t)\in E$ implies $s\le0$ -- that is, the first coordinate of any point in $E$ is $\le0$. Let
\begin{equation*}
    \ga_i^*(A):=\ga^*(\{x_i^*\}\times A)
\end{equation*}
for all Borel subsets $A$ of $E$.
To simplify writing, suppose that the $x_i^*$'s are pairwise distinct.
Then
\begin{equation*}
    C(\ga^*)=\sum_{i\in[N]}\int_E|x_i^*-y|^2\,\ga_i^*(dy). 
\end{equation*}
(Otherwise, first rewrite $\sum_{i\in[N]}\al_i\de_{x_i}$ as $\sum_{i\in[n]}\beta_j\de_{z_j}$ with pairwise distinct $z_j$'s and appropriate $n$ and $\beta_j$'s.)
Also, $\ga_1^*(\p E)\le\ga^*(\{x_1^*,\dots,x_N^*\}\times\p E)=\ell(\p E)=0$ and hence $$\ga_1^*(E^\circ)=\ga_1^*(E)-\ga_1^*(\p E)=\ga_1^*(E)=\al_1>0.$$
Therefore and because the first coordinate of any point in $E$ is $\le0$, the first coordinate of the barycenter $\bar x_1^*$ of the measure $\ga_1^*$ is $<0$. So, $\bar x_1^*\ne(0,0)=x_1^*$. Also, $\bar x_1^*\in E$, since $E$ is convex.
Moreover, it is easy to see (say, by differentiation) that $\bar x_1^*$ is the unique minimizer of $\int_E|x-y|^2\,\ga_1^*(dy)$ over $x\in E$.
It follows that
\begin{equation*}
    C(\bar\ga^*)<C(\ga^*), \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
where
$\bar\ga^*\in\Ga$ is defined by the conditions
\begin{equation*}
    \bar\ga^*(\{x_i^*\}\times A)=\ga^*(\{x_i^*\}\times A) \quad\text{if }i\in\{2,\dots,N\},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \bar\ga^*(\{\bar x_1^*\}\times A)=\ga^*(\{x_1^*\}\times A) 
\end{equation*}
for all Borel $A\subseteq E$.
Inequality \eqref{3} contradicts the optimality of $\ga^*$. $\quad\Box$

I get your point Iosif, complete and nice reasoning. Many thanks. Maybe just a typo: "barycentre" not "baricenter"?

@Fawen90 : Thank you for your comment. The spelling is now fixed.

The minimizers cannot lie on the boundary. In fact, denote by $E_i \subset E$ the set of all points which are transported to $x_i^*$. Then, $x_i^*$ has to be the center of mass of $E_i$ and, thus, cannot lie on the boundary.
I would also like to mention that this problem is well understood, see, e.g.,
http://doi.org/10.1137/141000993
and the references therein.

Thanks for the comment. I don't know how to prove rigorously why $x_i^$ must be the center. Take the uploaded photo for example, if the $x_i^$ is lying at the boundary, what will happen to contradict the optimality? As the sub-region $E_i$ may totally have the mass $\alpha_i$

In your objective, you have the contribution $\int_{E_i} | x_i^* - x|^2 , \mathrm d \ell(x)$. The derivative of this term w.r.t. $x_i^$ is zero if and only if $x_i^$ is the center of mass.

It is not so clear to me as $E_i$ also depends on $x_i$. Differentiating w.r.t. $x_i$ yields some expression depending not only on $‖x_i-x‖^2$ but also $E_i$.

Do you mind providing a complete reasoning by detailing your ideas? Many thx

No, you fix $E_i$ and only vary $x_i$. You can think of the entire process as a two-stage problem: In the first stage, you fix the regions $E_i$ and in the second stage you just optimize over the $x_i$. In the second stage, the $E_i$ are fixed and the optimization w.r.t. $x_i$ can be solved in closed form. The remaining optimization over $E_i$ is delicate.

Thanks for the reply. I'm still not convinced. Could you please write your full reasoning?

My reason is already in the second comment. You just have to compute the derivative, which is a standard computation.
